# jQuery Ajax File Upload to ASP.NET web service with JSON response

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file using jQuery Ajax to a c# Web Service (.asmx). The file is then processed by the Web Service and the result of the operation is returned asynchronously to the calling JavaScript.

The file upload works. However, it requires that I omit the option `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` when calling the `$.ajax()` function. And this causes the result not to be serialized as XML rather than the expected JSON. And this, in turn, causes jQuery to call the `error` handler instead of the `success` handler.

This is my client-side code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: global.ajaxServiceUrl + '/StartStructureSynchronisation',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    //Ajax events
    success: function (msg) {
      // this handler is never called
    error: function () {
      // this handler is called even when the call returns HTTP 200 OK
    },
    data: data, // this is a valid FormData() object
    //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

And this is my server-side code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string StartStructureSynchronisation()
{
    return this.Execute(delegate
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count == 0)
        {
            Global.StructureSyncResult = new SyncResult() { Result = false, Log = new List<string>() { "No file uploaded." } };
        }
        else if (!new List<string>() { ".xls", ".xlsx" }.Contains(Path.GetExtension(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].FileName).ToLower()))
        {
            Global.StructureSyncResult = new SyncResult() { Result = false, Log = new List<string>() { String.Format("({0}) is not a valid Excel file.", HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].FileName) } };
        }
        else
        {
            Global.StructureSyncResult = new Synchronization().SyncStructure(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream, ref Global.DocSyncCurrent, ref Global.DocSyncMax);
        }

        return Global.Serializer.Serialize(Global.StructureSyncResult);
    });
}
```

So, basically, what I am looking for is one of two things:

- Either upload the file using `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`. That way, the response will be serialized as JSON. I could even access the file as a parameter of my WebMethod instead of using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files`.
- Or find a way to force the WebService to always serialize the returned value as JSON, regardless of what the client says.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance and kind regards,

Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ajax Library `query.ajax_upload.0.6.js`, this is simple to use.

My code is Just for hint !

Button1 is basically the button to select the file from File Selector dialog .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function  uploadFile(parameters) {
        /* example 1 */
        var button = $('#button1'), interval;
        $.ajax_upload(button, {
            action: "FileHandler.ashx?test=" + $("#paramter").val(),
            name: Selectedval,
            onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
                StartLoading();
            },
            onComplete: function (file, response) {                 
                StopLoading();                  
            }
        });
        uploadButton();//Register Event
    });
});

<html>
    <a id="button1"  style="width: 70%" class="button orange">Select File</a>
</html>
```

On Server Side, You can write httpFile handler;

```
public class FileHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //For multiple files
        foreach (string f in context.Request.Files.AllKeys)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[f];
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName)) {
                string test = file.FileName;
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While your solution may allow to return a JSON serialized result, it totally bypasses the web service. Can you think of a solution that does still involve the web service?